# PHP / Wordpress - Integate a WordPress Function with Existing PHP Code for Twitter

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter

I have the following PHP code that I am using to pull Tweets:

```
<?php
class TwitterFeed {
    public $tweets = array();
    public function __construct($user, $limit = 5) {
        $user = str_replace(' OR ', '%20OR%20', $user);
        $feed = curl_init('http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=from:'. $user .'&rpp='. $limit);
        curl_setopt($feed, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($feed, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        $xml = curl_exec($feed);
        curl_close($feed);
        $result = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
        foreach($result->entry as $entry) {
            $tweet = new stdClass();
            $tweet->id = (string) $entry->id;
            $user = explode(' ', $entry->author->name);
            $tweet->user = (string) $user[0];
            $tweet->author = (string) substr($entry->author->name, strlen($user[0])+2, -1);
            $tweet->title = (string) $entry->title;
            $tweet->content = (string) $entry->content;
            $tweet->updated = (int) strtotime($entry->updated);
            $tweet->permalink = (string) $entry->link[0]->attributes()->href;
            $tweet->avatar = (string) $entry->link[1]->attributes()->href;
            array_push($this->tweets, $tweet);
        }
        unset($feed, $xml, $result, $tweet);
    }
    public function getTweets() { return $this->tweets; }
}
$feed = new TwitterFeed('trekradio', 4);
$tweets = $feed->getTweets();

?>
```

I need to replace 'trekradio' in this line $feed = new TwitterFeed('trekradio', 4); so that it uses the following code.  This code defines the Twitter ID on a Dynamic Basis from a Database Field.

```
<?php if (have_posts()) { $flag = true;  while (have_posts()) { the_post();
if ($flag) { $value = get_cimyFieldValue(get_the_author_ID(), 'twitter-username');
if ($value != NULL) echo . cimy_uef_sanitize_content($value) . ;
$flag = false;    }}} ?>
```

Can someone show me how to integrate the code so that it will properly function?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The assumption I am making is that $value is the variable you will want to send through as the parameter?

I'm also assuming that the TwitterFeed class is accessible from where you are trying to run the second snippet of code.

The final assumption is that cimy_uef_sanitize_content returns a value that is valid to be passed as the parameter to the TwitterFeed constructor.

Remove the $feed and $tweets line from below the class (unless you explicitly require it to be run against trekradio).

Then use the following code:

```
<?php 
if (have_posts()) { 
    $flag = true;  
    while (have_posts()) { 
        the_post();
        if ($flag) { 
            $value = get_cimyFieldValue(get_the_author_ID(), 'twitter-username');
            if ($value != NULL) {
                $feed = new TwitterFeed(cimy_uef_sanitize_content($value), 4);
                $tweets = $feed->getTweets();
                // Do whatever you need to do with your Tweets here
            }
            $flag = false;    
        }
    }
} ?>
```

But why are you asking this question again?  It was surely already answered in 
[PHP - An Echo inside of an existing function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6573426/php-an-echo-inside-of-an-existing-function)

EDIT:  Question:  What is the difference between 'twitter-username' and the value you want to send to the $user parameter in your TwitterFeed constructor?  If these are the same it could be simplified.

Comment: The reason I am asking again is because I made a mistake in the previous question, and although the solution worked in the context of the code I posted there, the code here is slightly different.   The previous code was pulling the database variable of a specific user where in the above code, it detects the user that "owns" the page you are currently on, and pulls their twitter username for their feed.  Hope that makes sense.